# org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpa-2.0, dereference, jpa-2.1

I am trying following hql query to execute

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM BillDetails as bd
 WHERE bd.billProductSet.product.id = 1002
   AND bd.client.id                 = 1
```

But it is showing

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection 
[billdetail0_.bill_no.billProductSet] with element property reference [product] 
[select count(*) from iland.hbm.BillDetails as bd where bd.billProductSet.product.id=1001 and bd.client.id=1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode$1.buildIllegalCollectionDereferenceException(DotNode.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.checkLhsIsNotCollection(DotNode.java:558)
```

Comment: Can you add your classes' definitions? Do they contain relationship definitions in them?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

`billProductSet` is a `Collection`. 
As such, it does not have an attribute named `product`.

`Product` is an attribute **of the elements** of this `Collection`.

You can fix the issue by **joining** the collection **instead of dereferencing** it:

```sql
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM BillDetails        bd 
  JOIN bd.billProductSet  bps 
 WHERE bd.client.id       = 1
   AND bps.product.id     = 1002
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my testing, if billProductSet is got be @JoinTable, and the relation is ManyToMany.

Comment: @Stony It **does** work with `@JoinTable` and `@ManyToMany`. I've that running right now.

Comment: Just for reference: in my case I was already doing the join of the collection but without giving it an alias it won't work. Thanks!

Comment: Only JOIN isn't worked for me. I used LEFT JOIN for my query.

Answer (score 1):

because billProduct is one to many mapping and there is many billProduct entity from one BillDetails entity you can't dereference  it in query.you must join BillDetails  model to billProduct and filter result with where cluase.