# Spring Boot Data JPA Querying an Entity with a Collection which has @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, collections, jpql

I have an entity named Club which has a @ManytoMany relationship with an entity named Type. This type has various tags for clubs, such as whether it's a football club or else a swimming club likewise. So a club could have multiple types also a certain type could be shared among clubs. When I want to select a club I also want to display the tags associated with the club accessing the type collection. How I am suppose to achieve this?

```
@Data
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Club {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String shortName;

    @Column(length = 80)
    private String description;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String email;

    private boolean status;

    @Lob
    private Blob logo;

    @Lob
    private Blob cover;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String website;

    private double longitude;

    private double latitude;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String registrationId;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date registrationDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastActiveDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club")
    private List<Favourite> favourites;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Type> type;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Address address;

}
@Entity
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Type {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String tag;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "type")
    private List<User> user;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "type")
    private List<Club> club;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdDate;

}
```

in the ClubRespository.java I am trying to access the type collection's tag variable like this.

```
@Repository
public interface ClubRepository extends JpaRepository<Club, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.service.payload.response.ClubSend(c.id, c.name, c.type.tag, c.shorName, c.description, c.email, c.logo, c.cover, c.longitude, c.latitude, c.address) FROM Club c JOIN c.type WHERE c.id=c.type.club.id")
    List<Club> findAllClubs();

}
```

ClubSend is a DTO class I created to map the fields I want to present, however when I am doing so, I am receiving this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [club0_.id.type] with element property reference [tag] [SELECT new com.vayemo.mysponsor.service.payload.response.ClubSend(c.id, c.name, c.type.tag, c.shorName, c.description, c.email, c.logo, c.cover, c.longitude, c.latitude, c.address) FROM com.vayemo.mysponsor.service.model.Club c JOIN c.type WHERE c.id=c.type.club.id]

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [club0_.id.type] with element property reference [tag] [SELECT new com.vayemo.mysponsor.service.payload.response.ClubSend(c.id, c.name, c.type.tag, c.shorName, c.description, c.email, c.logo, c.cover, c.longitude, c.latitude, c.address) FROM com.vayemo.mysponsor.service.model.Club c JOIN c.type WHERE c.id=c.type.club.id]

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [club0_.id.type] with element property reference [tag]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `c.type` in the Query is a List and therefore `c.type.club` cannot be dereferenced. If you want to access the type object, you need to provide an alias to it during the join (like this `... FROM Club c JOIN c.type t ...`), but as far as I know, your where clause is implicit in the declaration of the `@ManyToMany` relation. If you want more details check [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24751098/2148091).

Comment: Hi, I tried the solution in the link yet I am receiving the error! @Query("SELECT new com.vayemo.mysponsor.service.payload.response.ClubSend(c.id, c.name, t.tag, c.shortName, c.description, c.email, c.logo, c.cover, c.longitude, c.latitude, c.address) FROM Club c JOIN c.type t WHERE c.id=t.club.id")

Comment: after removing the implicit WHERE  this worked.